# Hud with shaders (opengl-es 2.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

How to draw a HUD using shaders on opengl es 2.0?

I have a shader which draws a textured quad on screen, it uses MVP matrix. The quad has it own vertices which are independent of view position and so on (cause of MVP matrix)

```
Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3f, 17);
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

I'd like to show the same quad on the top right corner (like a button or something else, HUD).
As I understand, i need create an ortho matrix instead of "frustumM", but what should i do later? How vertex shader should use vertices of quad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, You have your ortho matrix and quad, so whats the problem, translate modelview matrix of your quad to desired position (x,y,z=0), multiply it by ortho matrix , pass multiplied matrix to vertex shader, multiply vert position by your matrix and done :), i am not using any lookat function in my code to do this, but i have own code for matrices computation its partially code from some bada tutorial, for projection matrix i have other function.

```
  void
    Letter::Ortho(Matrix* result, float fovy, float aspect, float nearZ, float farZ)
    {
        GLfloat frustumW, frustumH;

        frustumH = tanf(fovy / 360.0f * PI) * nearZ;
        frustumW = frustumH * aspect;

        Frustum(result, -frustumW, frustumW, -frustumH, frustumH, nearZ, farZ);
    }

    void
    Letter::LoadIdentity(Matrix* result)
    {
        memset(result, 0x0, sizeof(Matrix));
        result->m[0][0] = 1.0f;
        result->m[1][1] = 1.0f;
        result->m[2][2] = 1.0f;
        result->m[3][3] = 1.0f;
    }


    void
    Letter::Frustum(Matrix *result, float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float nearZ, float farZ)
    {
        float   deltaX = right - left;
        float   deltaY = top - bottom;
        float   deltaZ = farZ - nearZ;
        Matrix  frustum;

        if ((nearZ <= 0.0f) || (farZ <= 0.0f) ||
            (deltaX <= 0.0f) || (deltaY <= 0.0f) || (deltaZ <= 0.0f))
        {
             return;
        }

        frustum.m[0][0] = 2.0f * nearZ / deltaX;
        frustum.m[0][1] = frustum.m[0][2] = frustum.m[0][3] = 0.0f;

        frustum.m[1][1] = 2.0f * nearZ / deltaY;
        frustum.m[1][0] = frustum.m[1][2] = frustum.m[1][3] = 0.0f;

        frustum.m[2][0] = (right + left) / deltaX;
        frustum.m[2][1] = (top + bottom) / deltaY;
        frustum.m[2][2] = -(nearZ + farZ) / deltaZ;
        frustum.m[2][3] = -1.0f;

        frustum.m[3][2] = -2.0f * nearZ * farZ / deltaZ;
        frustum.m[3][0] = frustum.m[3][1] = frustum.m[3][3] = 0.0f;

        Multiply(result, &frustum, result);
    }
```

So, with this code :

```
LoadIdentity(&matPerspective);
Ortho(&matPerspective, 60.0f, TEXMANAGER.aspect, -1.0f, 20.0f);
LoadIdentity(&matModelview);
Translate(&matModelview, x ,y ,z);
Scale(&matModelview,size);
//Rotate(&matModelview, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Multiply(&posMatrix, &matModelview, &matPerspective);
```

And pass posMatrix to shader :)

Comment: how to compute the intervals of screen (0,0,maxXcoord,maxYcoord)? lets say i want to place at the right corner, how do i know that x,y is in the translated screen position?

Comment: How do I know where is a corner using ortho projection?

Comment: Well, using my code, Center of screen is 0.0 x 0.0, right bottom corner is -1.0 -1.0