# glFrustrum variant in Opengl ES 2.0 - how fix blank screen?

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Well question is similiar to my previous one about glOrtho variant
[glOrtho OpenGL es 2.0 variant how fix blank screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617467/glortho-opengl-es-2-0-variant-how-fix-blank-screen)

Triangle below is draw perfectly at ortho projection (without projection it's squashed triangle, instead of the three equal sides triangle on rectangle viewport)

```
GLfloat triangle_vertices[] =
                 {
                -0.5, -0.25, 0.0,
                 0.5, -0.25, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.559016994, 0.0
                 };
```

Ortho matrix code:

```
typedef float[16] matrix;

void ortho_matrix(float right, float left, float bottom, float top, float near, float far, matrix result)
  {
// First Column
    result[0] = 2.0 / (right - left);
    result[1] = 0.0;
    result[2] = 0.0;
    result[3] = 0.0;

// Second Column
    result[4] = 0.0;
    result[5] = 2.0 / (top - bottom);
    result[6] = 0.0;
    result[7] = 0.0;

// Third Column
   result[8] = 0.0;
   result[9] = 0.0;
   result[10] = -2.0 / (far - near);
   result[11] = 0.0;

// Fourth Column
    result[12] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
    result[13] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    result[14] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
    result[15] = 1;
  }
```

Setting my projection matrix to ortho, where aspect_ratio = screen_width/screen_heigth

```
  ortho_matrix(-aspect_ratio, aspect_ratio, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, PROJECTION_MATRIX);
```

Task is to change ortho projection to perspective, so i write function for this
**UPD: changed to col-major**

```
void frustum_matrix(float right, float left, float bottom, float top, float near, float far, matrix result)
{
        // First Column
    result[0] = 2 * near / (right - left);
    result[1] = 0.0;
    result[2] = 0.0;
    result[3] = 0.0;

    // Second Column
    result[4] = 0.0;
    result[5] = 2 * near / (top - bottom);
    result[6] = 0.0;
    result[7] = 0.0;

    // Third Column
    result[8] = (right + left) / (right - left);
    result[9] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    result[10] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
    result[11] = -1;

    // Fourth Column
    result[12] = 0.0;
    result[13] = 0.0;
    result[14] = -(2 * far * near) / (far - near);
    result[15] = 0.0;
 }
```

Setting my projection to frustum matrix, where aspect_ratio = screen_width/screen_heigth

```
  frustum_matrix(-aspect_ratio, aspect_ratio, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1, 1.0, PROJECTION_MATRIX);
```

Well i peek matrix at glFrustrum page http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrustum.xml, but matrix for ortho func is from same source and works fine. Anyway i see similiar frustum matrix at various places like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812983/1039175 frustum function.

All what i got is blank screen, viewport and other stuff related to drawning is set right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your matrix indices are transposed from glFrustum's doc page. Do you transpose the matrix before uploading it? OpenGL typically refers to column vector matrices, so if you're copying the equations from glFrustum, the indices should look like this:

```
[0]  [4]  [ 8]  [12]
[1]  [5]  [ 9]  [13]
[2]  [6]  [10]  [14] 
[3]  [7]  [11]  [15]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that I'm too lazy to read your code, but... assuming your clear color is set to white, it could be that you didn't set the viewport :

Make sure you call this at least once before rendering:

```
GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
GLsizei width = viewport[2];
GLsizei height = viewport[3];
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

As for some general advice: don't try to reinvent the wheel with rewriting the matrix code (unless perhaps for some academic purpose). If you consider switching to c++ it's worth checking out the glm library : http://glm.g-truc.net/

It has replacements for exactly those matrix functions you are trying to implement and then some... I use it myself and it's a fantastic math lib to work with as it is specifically aimed towards opengl-es 2.0 and glsl.

Comment: viewport was set, i am aware of GLM of course, you got the point - academic purpose, anyway + 1